# Motion Blur with WebGL and three.js

Tags: javascript, animation, 3d, webgl, three.js

Is there a way to achieve high-performance motion-blur effect in WebGL?

I'm using Three.js, and the scene is a few simple plane objects with different textures. I move the camera in x axis.

Comment: There are better ways to do it, but this could be a start: http://bkcore.com/blog/3d/webgl-three-js-animated-selective-glow.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This example does a post processing pass of motionblur:
http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_materials_cubemap_dynamic.html

Comment: I think this is the updated link? https://threejs.org/examples/?q=cubemap#webgl_materials_cubemap_dynamic GitHub: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/webgl_materials_cubemap_dynamic.html